# Two finger swipe in Ubuntu 22.04 lts

Tags: 22.04, gestures

I just moved to Ubuntu linux from Fedora and was wondering why 22.04 doesn't support two-finger horizontal scroll to move back/forward through your browsing history. I had this feature on fedora and was happy about it, although it was not enabled on chrome by default. How do I make it enabled on firefox/chrome?

Comment: Do you run Wayland? You have to be running Wayland (on real hardware, not a VM) for two finger swipe to work.